# Is a coronal mass ejection (CME) synonymous with a solar particle event (SPE)?

Tags: terminology, cme, solar-flares

Having read [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection), [this Space SE answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6034/13678), and [this link](http://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/faqs/spaceradiation.html), I'm curious:  Is a "coronal mass ejection" the same thing as (synonymous with) a "solar particle event"?

If not, then what is/are the difference(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are not the same, though they can be caused by similar phenomena.

As the Wikipedia article you cite mentions, a coronal mass ejection is an unusual release of plasma. That plasma is released into the solar wind.

What makes a solar particle event different is that the plasma, once released, is then accelerated to greater speed/energy. The particles in an SPE can penetrate the atmosphere and cause ionization: particles in a CME are less energetic, but still sufficiently powerful to distort the magnetosphere.

I believe you will find the Wikipedia article on solar particle events to be interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_particle_event